# Using Groupyby on data to form box chart

Tags: python-3.x

I have (x,y) that looks like this:

```
[(0.32,0.5), (0.23, 0.3), (0.12, 0.5), (0.14, 0.2)...]
```

I want to create a box chart like this https://plot.ly/python/box-plots/

where the x axis are intervals like `0-0.1, 0.1-0.2 ...`

and the y are the y values in (x, y).

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Do you wish to use plotly or you want to this in native matplotlib.

Comment: Either is fine, I was wondering how to get the data in the format I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work. It's a very rough implementation but I think you would get the idea. I ended up using pandas for this example but I think you can equivalently do this using numpy.

```
def fnc(data):
    data[3]=[0]*len(data)
    for i in range(1, 10):
        data.loc[data[0].between(i*0.1, (i+1)*0.1),3]=i*0.1


data=[(0.32,0.5), (0.23, 0.3), (0, 0.8), (0.12, 0.5), 
        (0.14, 0.2), (0.25, 0.45), (0.17, 0.4)]
data=pandas.DataFrame(data)
fnc(data)
y = data.iloc[:, 1].values
x = data.iloc[:, 2].values

trace1 = go.Box(
    y=y,
    x=x
)
data = [trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    yaxis=dict(
        title='normalized moisture',
        zeroline=False
    ),
    boxmode='group'
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot(fig)
```

Here is the following plot I got.
[image]